# How to upload data more than once using Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-6

I'm trying to make a system where an admin creates a project template, and then templates for both text (limit on characters) and images (height/width and file extension)

When I have one template, the code works perfectly and I can even upload multiple texts/images with just one template.

But the problem comes when I create a 2nd text/image template, the template by itself is created without a problem, but when I want to upload something using that template, well...

[image: Error message]

With the problem being in this part of the code:

[image: Code with the error]

Here are the full codes:

Creation of the templates:

Textos_DescripcionController.php (controller of the text template) :

```php
public function store(Request $request){

        $request->validate([
            'nombre_texto' => ['required'],
            'min' => ['required'],
            'max' => ['required'],
        ]);
        
        Textos_Descripcion::create($request->all());

        $data_txt = DB::table('textos__descripcions')
                ->max('id');

        $data_proyecto = $_POST['proyecto_id'];

        //dd($data_proyecto);

        Textos_Descripcion_Plantillas::insert(['proyecto_id' => $data_proyecto, 'texto_descripcion_id' => $data_txt]);
                    
        return redirect('/profile/' . auth()->user()->id);
    }
```

TextosController.php (texts by themselves):

```php
public function store(Request $request){

        $plantilla_id = $_POST['id_descr'];

        //Obtenemos ancho y alto de la plantilla

        $min = DB::table('textos__descripcions')
                ->select('min')
                ->where('id' , '=', $plantilla_id)
                ->first();

        $min_valor = $min->min;

        $max = DB::table('textos__descripcions')
                ->select('max')
                ->where('id' , '=', $plantilla_id)
                ->first();

        $max_valor = $max->max;

        //ahora obtenemos los ancho y alto de la imagen

        $largo = strlen($_POST["texto"]);

        
        //ahora comparamos

        if($min_valor > $largo || $max_valor < $largo){
                
                echo "El texto no cumple con los estandares, la imagen debe ser desde " . $min->min . " hasta " . $max->max . "y tu texto tiene " . $largo . " caracteres ";

                dd($largo);
                
                return redirect('/profile/' . auth()->user()->id);
        };

        $paro = "Aqui toy";

        
        
        echo "Succes, La imagen cumple con los estandares, la imagen debe ser desde " . $min->min . " hasta " . $max->max . "y tu texto tiene " . $largo . " caracteres ";

        $request->validate([
            'caption' => ['required'],
            'texto' => ['required'],
            'id_descr' => ['required'],
        ]);

        //dd($paro);

        Textos::create($request->all()); //

        //Datos a tabla intermedia

        $data_img = DB::table('textos__descripcion__plantillas')
                ->select('id')
                ->where('id' ,'=', $plantilla_id)
                ->first();

        $data_img_valor = $data_img->id;

        $id_proyecto = DB::table('proyectos')
                ->select('id')
                ->where('id','=', $data_img_valor)
                ->first();

        $id_proyecto_valor = $id_proyecto->id; //I'm getting problems here

        $id_txt = DB::table('textos')
                ->max('id');


        Textos_Proyectos::insert(['proyectos_id' => $id_proyecto_valor , 'textos_id' => $id_txt]);

        return redirect('/profile/' . auth()->user()->id);
    }
```

I used a dd() right before the line of code that gives me problems, which gave a null. And to me this doesn't make sense, because it works with the 1st template, when I use the dd() I get the id of what I'm uploading:

[image: dd() of the 1st upload]

Why is this happening?

I apologize is the question is too vague, if it lacks details please point it out

EDIT: I decided to change the first() to get() in the line that's throwing me problems, and I got an empty array

Comment: Change `$plantilla_id = $_POST['id_descr'];` to `$plantilla_id = $request->id_descr;`

Comment: @TalhaF. I'll do that

Comment: Hi, first erros comes from $_POST, instead use $request->variable_name

Comment: My general rule is that if you are using `DB` facade, you're probably doing something wrong. You should be able to just do `Proyecto::findOrFail($data_img_valor)->id ?? null;` to get the value in question. You also should not be inserting into a pivot table directly, this suggests to me you do not have relations set up correctly.